# dump_stack() in Linux kernel doesn't print the addresses of functions

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel, stack-trace, kernel-module

I have a test `Linux kernel module` which prints the `dump_stack()`. But it prints an incomplete trace as it does not have the function addresses printed. I use a `Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS` with `4.15.0-142-generic` kernel and `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y` is set in `/boot/config-4.15.0-142-generic`.

My questions:

(1) Why the function's address is not printed? I can dump the symbol table using `objdump -t`.

(2) Trace shows that `dump_stack()` is called from `module_level_init` . However it is `module_level_init()->module_level_2()->module_level_3()`

Following is the `dmesg` output:

```
[ 1347.807370] CPU: 7 PID: 13262 Comm: insmod Tainted: P           OE    4.15.0-142-generic #146~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[ 1347.807371] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[29020.752090] Call Trace:
[29020.752096]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x8b
[29020.752097]  ? 0xffffffffc0730000
[29020.752099]  module_level_init+0x1a/0x1000 [kern]
[29020.752102]  do_one_initcall+0x55/0x1b0
[29020.752103]  ? _cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[29020.752105]  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x165/0x1c0
[29020.752106]  do_init_module+0x5f/0x222
[29020.752108]  load_module+0x1894/0x1ea0
[29020.752111]  ? ima_post_read_file+0x83/0xa0
[29020.752112]  SYSC_finit_module+0xe5/0x120
[29020.752113]  ? SYSC_finit_module+0xe5/0x120
[29020.752115]  SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
[29020.752116]  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
```

The kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

int module_level_3(void)
{
        dump_stack();
        return 0;
}

int module_level_2(void)
{
        module_level_3();
        return 0;
}

static int __init module_level_init(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world\n");
        module_level_2();
        return 0;
}

static void __exit module_level_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, world\n");
}

module_init(module_level_init);
module_exit(module_level_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += kern.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

objdump

```
#objdump -Sdlr kern.ko

kern.ko:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <module_level_3>:
module_level_3():
   0:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  5 <module_level_3+0x5>
                        1: R_X86_64_PC32        __fentry__-0x4
   5:   55                      push   %rbp
   6:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <module_level_3+0xe>
                        a: R_X86_64_PC32        dump_stack-0x4
   e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  10:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  11:   c3                      retq
  12:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
  16:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  1d:   00 00 00

0000000000000020 <module_level_2>:
module_level_2():
  20:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  25 <module_level_2+0x5>
                        21: R_X86_64_PC32       __fentry__-0x4
  25:   55                      push   %rbp
  26:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  29:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  2e <module_level_2+0xe>
                        2a: R_X86_64_PC32       dump_stack-0x4
  2e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  30:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  31:   c3                      retq

Disassembly of section .init.text:

0000000000000000 <init_module>:
module_level_init():
   0:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  5 <init_module+0x5>
                        1: R_X86_64_PC32        __fentry__-0x4
   5:   55                      push   %rbp
   6:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
                        9: R_X86_64_32S .rodata.str1.1
   d:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  10:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  15 <init_module+0x15>
                        11: R_X86_64_PC32       printk-0x4
  15:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  1a <init_module+0x1a>
                        16: R_X86_64_PC32       dump_stack-0x4
  1a:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  1c:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  1d:   c3                      retq

Disassembly of section .exit.text:

0000000000000000 <cleanup_module>:
module_level_exit():
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
                        4: R_X86_64_32S .rodata.str1.1+0x10
   8:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  10 <cleanup_module+0x10>
                        c: R_X86_64_PC32        printk-0x4
  10:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  11:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: Probably, the compiler **inlines** functions `module_level_2` and `module_level_3` into the `module_level_init` one. This can be checked by examine code of `module_level_init` in the object file after disassemble. E.g. `objdump -Sdlr kernel.ko`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, ```
Disassembly of section .init.text:

0000000000000000 <module_level_3>:module_level_3():
 
0000000000000012 <module_level_2>:module_level_2():

0000000000000024 <init_module>: module_level_init():
``` It shows all the functions.

Comment: The output you show just means that the object file **has** all three functions. You still need to check whether `module_level_init` actually **calls** `module_level_2` one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev , Added ```printk``` with function names and verified that the functions are called in the order.

Comment: What do you mean by "Added `printk` with function names"? If you print value of `__FUNCTION__ ` macro, that it just reflects function boundaries in the **source** file, not the ones in the **object** file. You need to look into the object file. And output of `dump_stack` even hints you where to look: `module_level_init+0xe/0x1000 [kern]` means that you need to find in the `.init.text` section address of the beginning of the `module_level_init` function and add `0xe` to that address. Resulted address is a "return address", it points immediately after the `call` instruction.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that @Tsyvarev answered that in the very first comment?

Comment: @0andriy, The functions are included in the object file. I think that clarifies functions are not inlined. I did not understand if the functions are not inlined, why it should not call the functions in order. Also I am seeking answer for my first question; the possible reason for not printing the address of functions.

Comment: It is unclear from your question and comments. I, btw, can't reproduce the existence of the module intermediate functions. You probably need to describe what exactly you have done. Moreover, the code you put can't be compiled. **Fix** your question, please.

Comment: @0andriy, ```#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

int module_level_3(void)
{
        dump_stack();
        return 0;
}
int module_level_2(void)
{
        module_level_3();
        return 0;
}
static int module_level_init(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world\n");
        module_level_2();
        return 0;
}

static void module_level_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, world\n");
}
module_init(module_level_init);
module_exit(module_level_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: @0andriy, There was a bug in my code. if you see the code, I have added a ```__init``` with all the functions. I think that could have tricked the compiler. Now the ```dump_stack``` prints in the below order

Comment: BTW, Can I edit the question with the corrected code or it should remain as such ?

Comment: What you have done by dropping `__init` annotation is that the compiler can't inline them anymore and you got the sequence printed, but it's not the root cause (you simply hidden the symptoms), see again given comments. Note `__init` is a **right** think to do in the mentioned case and it's not a bug, now you have a (subtle) bug in the code.

Comment: You may extend your question with the update(s).

Comment: corrected the question